# Functional components in same class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a navbar, and I need to use the same code to add a new item, so I have made a function, but I wanted to know if there is any better way to do it or how i can improve the current code, thanks.

```
import { Component } from 'react'

export default class NavBar extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
        <ul>
            <NavBarItem name='Home'/>
            <NavBarItem name='Contact'/>
        </ul>
    )
  }
}

function NavBarItem(props) {
    return <li>{props.name}</li>;
}
```

Comment: Looks reasonable, though personally I'd make the NavBar functional too, it'll be shorter and easier to understand at a glance

Comment: How about using `map` and sending the nav-items as *props* for NavBar ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer to this question, as I think it leaves a lot of room for opinion, but personally I'd probably do something like this:

```
import { Component } from 'react'

export default NavBar = () => {
  const NavBarItem = ({name}) => <li>{name}</li>;

  return (<ul>
    <NavBarItem name='Home'/>
    <NavBarItem name='Contact'/>
  </ul>);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

search **vue router** or **router.js** the best way to built a header router and importing a all vue components

example like this.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Home from './Admin/pages/Home'
import Profile from './Admin/pages/Profile'
import Contact from './Admin/pages/Contact'
const routes = [
    {
        path:'/',
        component:Home
    },
    {
        path:'/profile',
        component:Profile
    },
    {
        path:'/contact',
        component:Contact
    }
]
export default new Router({
    mode:'history',
    routes
})
```

hopefully this source can help you